# Use Windows Terminal on PhpStorm?

Tags: windows, terminal, phpstorm, settings

I would like to know how to use Windows Terminal on PhpStorm?

I went to `"Settings> Terminal"`, and tried to change the terminal path to :

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe`

But no effects

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible: Windows Terminal is not a shell, it's a terminal emulator that has its own window/UI. It is just another front end to the existing shells that runs a shell (powershell, cmd, wsl) under the hood. PhpStorm provides its own terminal emulator in *Terminal* tool window. It's impossible to integrate one terminal emulator inside another, because all integration is based on parsing ANSI/VT sequences from underlying shell.